# Square Payment - Create order and payment with javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend, square

I have a restaurant website from which a client can make order. After selecting articles on a cart, the client is sent to the checkout page in which he will introduce his information and his bank card. I want to make the payment process with Square API, but I want to do it in the client side (JavaScript) not in the server side (Java with Spring-Boot).

```js
async function createPayment(token) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        locationId,
        sourceId: token,
    });
    const paymentResponse = await fetch('/payment', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body,
    });
    if (paymentResponse.ok) {
        return paymentResponse.json();
    }
    const errorBody = await paymentResponse.text();
    throw new Error(errorBody);
}
```

How can I create a payment, an order and a client in the frontend. In the documentation of square, it is done with the Java API.

Comment: from the documentation, it seems to be http based, not java based. You just have to pass the correct information in the http post request. https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment. Not sure if i am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, but the request is in java.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, according the above documentation you can do a curl request, which is nothing more than a http request. We dont have access to your application so we cant tell you how to pass the information that the documentation states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Square client side API call aren't available. All API calls need to be server side. You’ll need to have this code written in PHP, ASP, Ruby, Java, or similar on the back end. This is code that runs behind the scenes on your hosting provider.

We do not allow API calls directly from the browser. This would expose your API credentials, which would allow anyone to gain access to your Square account.

Comment: In this example : https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/java_payment/src/main/resources/static/js/sq-payment-flow.js, the window.getPaymentRequest function sends line items and shipping contact to the server. This is similar  to what I need